# How do you address different objects in java?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

Ok so I started learning java a few days ago, and I didn't come too far... I ran into a problem regarding different objects and the constructor. So for this little project I need to use BlueJ since this is for school. This is not the code that we had in school, but this is a general problem, and the code is similar. So let's say we have this:

```
public class Pokemon {

    public String name;
    public String type;
    public int hpNow;
    public int hpMax;

    public void Pokemon(String oName, String oType, int oHpNow, int oHpMax) {
        name=oName;
        type=oType;
        hpNow=oHpNow;
        hpMax=oHpMax;
    }
}
```

So I've heard about the new operator, or keyword, not sure, that should create a new object now, however in BlueJ you can do that in the main menu, by kind of calling the constructor. We wanted to make an attack method now (a simple one, ignoring type and stuff), and what we did in my classes looked like this:

```
public void attack(Pokemon oName) {
    oName.lpNow=oName.lpNow-ap;
}
//and then some kind of System.out.println(); stuff
```

So... the thing I don't understand here is, how would I do that for different objects? I mean I have one Pokemon (not sure if that is an object) that uses the variables assigned directly under the class line, and one that uses the one from the constructor. I use the second object by using oName. followed by some stuff. If I made a third object using the constructor now, how would I use that one? I mean I would probably still use oName. followed by something, but I am using that for the second one already?? Is the first Pokemon that uses name instead of oName as example and doesn't need the . even an object?

Comment: I'm not really understanding the question at all. But one note: `public void attack(Pokemon oName)` here `oName` is really bad naming of your method argument. After all the argument you are passing to that method is not a single name, but an object of the type Pokemon. A name like `public void attack(Pokemon pokemonToAttack)` would be much clearer as it would tell the reader what tat argument actualy represents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding how classes work and your/your teacher's naming convention isn't very good.

First of all, the `oName` in the constructor is of type `String`, the one in the `attack` is referring to the Pokemon **object** itself. So in `attack` you are accessing the Pokemon's `hpNow` attribute and subtracting a number from it, **not a string**.

And when you use the `new` keyword to create an object, all the methods that you created in the class is accessible to that particular object. An object is a particular instance of the class Pokemon. So, if you have two objects let's say:

`Pokemon pikachu = new Pokemon(...)`

`Pokemon charmander = new Pokemon(...)`

You can do something like `charmander.attack(pikachu)`

Comment: yeah well, in blueJ the user can define the name himself so I wasn't sure how to use or find that out yourself, actually that is my naming convention, I will also read the other article Kayaman sent, thank you